# How to use digitalpersona one touch sdk java edition in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, sdk

I downloaded digitalpersona free one touch sdk (1.6.1): java edition. 
Installed the sdk and the java run time environment (RTE).
I would like to create my own user interface for fingerprint enrollment/verification using the sdk , however I dont know how to implement it in a java application in netbeans. Am relatively new to using netbeans and I have a project to do using fingerprint matching.

How do I use the package com.digitalpersona.onetouch.ui.swing.sample.Enrollment; and import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.*; ?

What do I need to import to the new java application for it to allow me to use the methods available in the sdk? Any dll or jar i need to call or add to the library?
Your guidance will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: If you look at where the SDK has been installed do you see any `.jar` files? I have never worked with this but usually all you need to do would be to add these JAR files in your class path (but adding them to your library folder basically)

Comment: Thanks, yes I finally found the .jar files!
They were in the sub sub folders and I didnt notice them.
And I successfully added them to the project library. Thanks for your help.

Comment: hey i'm also a noob in this... how did u do this can u please guide? PS:I tried to add the jar in the bin folder(which i suppose id the class path)

Comment: Hi ahhmarr are you using netbeans ide?
If you are- when you create a new project. It is listed under the project tab of the ide. (normally on your top left)
Expand the node of your project - you will see a list of folders. Simply right click on the libraries folder, and select "add jar/folder" then browse to where your .jar files are stored on your computer and they will be added to your library. You will then be able to call all the functions from the sdk.

Answer (score 3):

Although this answer is 4 years late, but I hope it helps make this community more helpful.

After installing the SDK on your development machine (Windows), you should navigate to the directory you installed the SDK (in my case, it is `C:/Program Files/DigitalPersona`, open `bin/java` and verify that the `dpotapi` jar executable exists. If it does, then you note the path to this jar file as this is your class path.

To add it to Netbeans, click on Projects in your IDE, right click on `Libraries` then choose `Add Jar/Folder` and from the dialog that pops up navigate to the directory where you had earlier found the `dpotapi.jar` file, click on it, then `Open`, and you are good to go.

Comment: After days of researching I happen to confirm those files are the correct ones! Thank you very much and god bless you :D!